# PG Search with Rails 4 - getting different results in development than production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, search

On rails 4 using Pg Search.

For a while I was stuck trying to get exact matches to display first. Well, I finally got that to work in development, but when I deployed to heroku it did not work anymore.

`Cream cheese` would display before `cheese`. `Coke zero` would display before `coke`. And so on. Has anyone had this issue? Having trouble finding documentation and don't know where to go from here. It is hard to diagnose any issues, as it works find in development.

This is what my scope looks like:

```
pg_search_scope :search, :against => :specific,
                       :using => { dmetaphone: {}, tsearch: { dictionary: 'english' }, 
                       trigram: {:threshold => 0.5} },
                       ignoring: :accents
```

Comment: Given your code is the same in both environments, have you compared locale and collation of your database tables? Maybe it is related to case sensitivity since capital letters are listed first...?